# Using R.NET with multiple AppDomains

Tags: .net, r.net

Is it possible to use [R.NET](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) from multiple AppDomains?  At the end of the [documentation](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation) there is a reference to "Multiple app domains", but no further information.

The scenario is that I have what is essentially a trading system IDE.  Each time a trading system is run, a new AppDomain is created for it to run in, so that the assembly can be unloaded, and the code can be modified and recompiled later.  A user [is reporting](http://www.rightedgesystems.com/forums/16149/R.Net-REngine.GetInstance-only-work-works-for-the-first-simulation) that when he tries to use R.NET from a system, it works the first time he runs it but after that it hangs and he has to restart the development environment.

Is there a way to properly clean up an R.NET connection so a new one can later be created in a different AppDomain, or some other way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that there is a clash between AppDomains in the .NET world (presumably because your trading platform uses them as isolated sandboxes) and that there can be only one R engine per process, initializable only once. This issue has arisen previously - see [this feature request](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/92) for more background.

R.NET could work around that with cross domain gymnastic, but this is complicated and may defeat the purpose of app domain isolation. One R engine per process is a non-negotiable thing so far as I know.